# Optimizing bicubic equation solver with numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, vectorization

I have some image manipulation software that works really well, but its pretty slow. I'm using numpy for somethings at the moment, but I cannot help but think I can leverage more of this library to get better gains.

Also, pardon me if "bicubic" isn't the right term here - I understand math, but suck at vocabulary ;)

My tool solves for the coefficients (a, b, ..., j) of a bicubic equation in the form of:

```
f(x,y) = ax^3 + by^3 + cx^2*y + dy^2*x + ex^2 + fy^2 + gxy + hx + iy + j
```

The way I do this is to first generate a solver using a smaller set of points from my source and target datasets. This is done by first "matrix rows" for each set with a shape of (n, 10), and then solving using a least squares. From there, we go through every other item in the source data, generate the "matrix row" and do an np.dot against the "solved" coefficient matrix.

```
import numpy as np

def matrix_row(x, y):
    row = [0] * 10
    row[0] = 1.0
    row[1] = x
    row[2] = y
    row[3] = x * y
    row[4] = y * y
    row[5] = x * x
    row[6] = (y * y) * x
    row[7] = (x * x) * y
    row[8] = y**3
    row[9] = x**3
    return row

def gen_matrix(items, num_items=24):
    mat = []
    for i in xrange(0, num_items):
        mat.append(_matrix_row(items[i, 0], items[i, 1]))
    return np.array(mat)

# Generate source data
n = 24
srcdata = np.random.rand(100, 2)
dstdata = np.random.rand(n, 2)

# Determine the coefficients for the solver for the first n components
# The resultant 'solved' matrix will be of shape (10, 2)
srcmat = gen_matrix(srcdata[:n, :], num_items=n)
solved, residuals, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(srcmat, dstdata)

# Apply the solution to all the src data
for item in srcdata:
    mrow = matrix_row(item[0], item[1])

    # Obviously, the print statements aren't important
    print 'orig   ', item
    print 'solved ', np.dot(mrow, solved)
    print '\n'
```

I have LOTS of data, so the for-loop in Python really kills the performance. Is there a more numpy-thonic way of optimizing this?

Comment: What's the shape of `solved`?

Comment: Hi! The shape of solved is (10L, 2L). I'll add a comment to the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach -

```
# Form an array of shape (10,100) that represents pairwise implementation
# of all those functions using all rows off srcdata
x,y = srcdata.T
a = np.ones((10,100))
a[1] = x
a[2] = y
a[3] = x * y
a[4] = y * y
a[5] = x * x
a[6] = (y * y) * x
a[7] = (x * x) * y
a[8] = y**3
a[9] = x**3

# Finally use dot product in one go to get solutions across all iterations
out = solved.T.dot(a).T
```

Comment: Ahh interesting! Thanks a lot, this certainly makes loads of sense now! FWIW, for ~2 million samples, execution time droped from ~13s to .5s.

Comment: @destructo Very kool! Not surprised though, those kinda speedups are usual when going from loopy Python to NumPy :)